# How to find the probability of event in the data below toghter with odds ratio and OD?

Tags: r, statistics, glm

We are working on the data from package boot and data downs.bc.

What is the probability of the event for a 20 year old? for a 30 year
old? Calculate the Odds ratio and OD model.

```
mod1 <- glm(cbind(r, m-r) ~ age, family = binomial, data = boot::downs.bc)
summary(mod1)
```

can I do it this way for the probability part?

```
-10.563690 + 20 * 0.137579= -6.43632

-10.563690 + 30* 0.137579= -5.06053
```

Comment: You're currently estimating the linear estimator (assuming your paramters are correct). That'll be the "log-odds ratio", To retrieve the odds ratio add `exp(...)`. You could also use `exp(predict(mod1, newdata = data.frame(age = c(30, 20))))`

Comment: @Oliver how about the OD model?

Comment: For that you'll have to be more specific. I don't have the faintest clue what the abbrevation "OD" is in this context.